# OnRedirectToLogin is missing on Framework 4.7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I would like to use `OnRedirectToLogin` Event (Which exists on ASP.NET Core but not in .NET Framework 4.7) to manipulate the way that ASP.NET Identity redirect **unauthenticated candidates** to the login page.

1. Is there any alternative for the above?
2. Does that mean that Microsoft start to create features gaps between the .NET Core and the .NET Framework and its another reason to start new project with .NET Core over .NET Framework?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any alternative for the above?

Yes. Subclass `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the [`AuthorizeAttribute.HandleUnauthorizedRequest`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L122-L126) method. `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` only fires when the user is not authorized.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filter.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(...);
    }
}
```

And then use `[CustomAuthorize]` everywhere you would normally use `[Authorize]`.

> Does that mean that Microsoft start to create features gaps between the .NET Core and the .NET Framework and its another reason to start new project with .NET Core over .NET Framework?

Since `AspNetCore` is a *completely different UI framework* with a new design, not an evolution of `ASP.NET MVC`, you can expect there to be gaps between them. Although, unless you are a library developer that wants to support both frameworks at the same time, I fail to see how this is an issue.

Comment: Do you have an idea regarding question #2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnApplyRedirect event on the CookieAuthenticationProvider. Note that the *context* parameter is a CookieApplyRedirectContext and not the standard HttpContext.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn450313(v=vs.113))

```
 var options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
       {
           AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = "Account/Login",
           Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
           {
               OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                   validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                   regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
               OnApplyRedirect = context =>
               {
                    //do something here
               }
           }                 
     };
}
```